# Why does DFS work when trying to find all valid words in a Boggle board

Tags: algorithm, graph, boggle

I was solving the Boggle game programmatically and noticed that Depth First Search can be used to find all valid combinations of letters in a board. A Boggle board is described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boggle).

Say we have a 4x4 board. For each character on the board, use DFS to find all paths in the board (the only rule is you can't use a single character more than once). Why does DFS work for this when a Boggle board isn't really a graph? Also, what other types of problems can DFS be applied to that are similar to this usage?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply DFS or other graph algorithms because you basically play on a [grid graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GridGraph.html) with diagonals as well.

[image]

Put your letters instead of the dots and you have your graph. Now why DFS would work here?

When you create a word in this game - you connect adjacent vertices and thus creating a path on the graph. So here is an approach which you can start with (and improve on).

1. Create a set of all words in English alphabet and a reasonable length of a word (let's assume that words are not longer than `N` chars)
2. Start iterating from the vertices and from each vertex invoke DFS that runs till the length `N`. For each of the words (that are bigger than 3 in the rules) check if it is in the dictionary and if it is - save them somewhere.

You can see that in my part of the graph you can easily find the word `TORUS`.

**Why does it make sense to use DFS and not BFS?** A couple of reasons are:

- easier to implement
- way smaller space complexity

**What is the complexity of my algorithm**
Assume that you have a a grid `n * m` and the longest word has a length `d`. Because in my algorithm you implement DFS from all the vertices and complexity of DFS is O(b^d) where an average branch is a little bit smaller than 8 (may be even smaller than 7 because you can't have loops here). The search in the set id O(1). So the complexity is `m * n * 8^d`.

**How can you improve it?** There is little sense in trying to search the word `TLRSOU` because there are no words in English alphabet that start with `TLR`. So a better idea is to store words in a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) and terminate fast the branches that do not makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

That's because it is (or can be) represented by a graph. Boggle words are made from adjacent letters that run horizontally, vertically, or diagonally. So you can make a graph of connections between letters, by following this rule. Additionally, DFS will not visit a node twice, because it keeps a list of nodes already visited. So it satisfies the other rule that a letter can be used only once.

DFS (and BFS, too), will eventually discover every path through the graph, so you can compare the list of paths so generated with a dictionary of valid words to determine the total number of valid words from a single Boggle board.

The most well-known use of DFS is of course for pathfinding - almost any space can be mapped into a graph and then the shortest or longest path found. DFS can be good for finding the radius of a graph, and thus the centre-most node. This can be useful for things like flood-fill algorithms, where you want to fill the interior of an irregular shape quickly, as the edge expansion will happen the fastest when started from the center of the graph.